# "We are sorry for the inconvenience! You can reopen the window to continue where you left off"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

This issue only happens when I am working on anything react related. I am currently learning react native and practicing react at the same time but when I open other projects that have nothing to do with react, the issue never comes up. The other similar questions I have checked on the visual studio code git hub and here on stack overflow mostly have no answers and the only one with an answer said I must reinstall visual studio code of which I have but the same issue persists. So now I am out of ideas about what to do because it happens every like 20 or 30 minutes and it is tiring so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Settings` option in VSCode and type `restoreWindows` and set the option in setting to `'none'`.
[image]